# Displaying activity(theme dialog) show above the Dialer in lockscreen?

Tags: android, android-activity

Need to show the Activity (Theme dialog) over the dialer with some information populated in activity like true caller. In unlocked phone, it is working well.

But in locked phone, it didnt work as expected. Did some googling and found few flags needs to be added to make dialog appear in lock screen.

## CallActivity.java

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG | LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
    LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

In the above code, i added changes related to make activity appear as dialog and few flags (FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD) related to make dialog work well in lock screen (but it didnt).

I also starting the activity with (from broadcast receiver)

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: have you got answer?

Answer (score -1):

add view on window manager with System Alert permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT; 
mParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
mParams.flags = 262184;

mWindowManager.addView(view, mParams);
```

Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.canDrawOverlays().